# Mount a SMB share's subfolder as a drive in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, network-shares, mount, samba

In Snow Leopard I was able to mount a subfolder of a Samba share directly using a path like the following in the "Connect to Server" Finder dialog:

```
smb://someserver/someshare/where/i/really/want/togo
```

Using that would create a mount in [/Volumes] with the name "togo". It was great for me since at my work we have several servers with the same share name that I need to be connected to simultaneously. I can no longer do this in OS X Lion.

What happens instead is I get several mounts named like "someshare", "someshare-1", "someshare-2", etc. Using the same path just mounts the share, not the subfolder.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use `mount_smbfs` in the Terminal to do this. However, a directory for the mount must first be created. Luckily, running `umount` removes that directory. But this is at least a starting point to create a better system.

Mounting:

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/togo
$ mount_smbfs smb://someserver/someshare/where/i/really/want/togo /Volumes/togo
```

Unmounting:

```
$ umount /Volumes/togo
```

Of course, unmounting should work fine through the finder.

Comment: This works, but is a pain. It would be great if this could be automated in some way.